# Accessing Shares on Windows Server 2003 Failing for some Computers

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, windows-server-2003

I'm updating our render farm computers to Windows8 because our software removed compatibility with XP64.

Every machine is getting a clean install of Windows8, Mapped drives set up, installed with our render software and that's it.

So far, no problems, but the latest machine cannot access the shares on our Windows Server 2003 machine. Nothing in my process has changed. It has the same login credentials as the server and every other render machine. It connects just fine to the Windows Server 2008 server on the same network.

I'm about 8 computers in with no problems, and now it's complaining about a Username and Password (even though it is absolutely correct). I checked all the other machines and they still connect to all the shares just fine.

I get the same results however I try to access the server. "Net Use" doesn't work, just browsing to the share doesn't work. No matter what, this machine is asking for a Username and Password that never works every time I try to access the 2003 server.

Comment: Running a domain? Try removing/re-adding it. Check date and time of client and make sure it's the same as the server.

Comment: Genius! It was the Time/Date. The CMOS battery on the render machine was dead and it was resetting the time every time I restarted. How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure the BIOS/Windows date and time matches the server.

Comment: By default, they must be within 5 minutes

Comment: As I don't know whether they're using a domain I've not mentioned about the 5 minutes because I know that's Kerberos. If not on domain, then, I believe, it uses NTLM and I don't know how long (or even if it is) time sensitive...